# Finding the upper/lower sum over a rectangle for f(x,y) = xy

Tags: integration, analysis

My book defines the upper and lower sums are as $U(f,P) = \sum^n_{j=1} sup_{R_j}f \ V(R_j)$ for some function $f$, $P$ a partition into $n$ rectangles $(R_j)$ with the volume as $V(R_j)$ the length of the rectangles edges, so area in $R^2$. (The lower sum is $inf(f)$ respectively)

I am asked to find the upper and lower sums for a function $f(x,y) = xy$ over the rectangle $R = [0,1]x[0,1]$ with partitions given by $\{0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},1 \}$.

Normally in the 1-dim case we would just split the interval up and then sum these based on the function times the partition size (so for example, if $f(x) = x$ and we just looked at $R = [0,1], P= \{0,1/4, etc\}$ then we would do $L(f,p) = f(0)*\frac{1}{4} + f(\frac{1}{4})*\frac{1}{4} + ...$). But I am not quite sure how to do this with the rectangle partitions.

Am I supposed to sum over each rectangle separately? So for example taking $L(f,p) = f(0,0)*\frac{1}{16}+ f(\frac{1}{4}, 0)*\frac{1}{16} + ... + f(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4})*\frac{1}{16}$ is this incorrect? Or should I be splitting up the larger rectangle (the $[0,1]x[0,1]$ total) and summing over just the $xy$ region in that somehow?

Comment: You need just to sum over each rectangle separately and that will give you an upper bound.

Comment: So is the lower sum I gave as an example correct then? With the lower sum I would choose the lower left vertice for my f(x,y) and then just multiply by the area (1/16) 16 times?

Comment: Yeah you're right. For example in $R_{1,1}$ you have that the maximum is $f(\frac 14, \frac 14) = \frac 1{16}$ and the minimum is $\frac(0,0) = 0$

Comment: Ok great, thanks!